# Xiaomi Music Player don't shows songs information

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, music-player, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Mi3 running Android 6.0 and there is a problem with the stock music player: some songs don't show the album cover or the artist. Other ones dont' show the name of the album.

What can be the problem? Is there a solution or I have to download another music player?

Comment: Could this just be evidence the tags on all your files is inconsistent? Is all the data present to show; you don't really say that in your post. There are tag readers that will enable you to find out whether the data is incomplete. Missing data in the source is not really a player problem.

Comment: I have all the tags in my songs, in fact other music players like Shuttle show all the information.